# tkeclipse - GUI colors assignments - Edit which file to fix?

Tags: configuration, eclipse-clp

The default settings for the installation of tkeclipse are unusable.

What I see get is this:

[image]

Also,

[image]

I looked thru the menu choices and there is no option there to make required changes.

Which file (or files) control the colour assignments and could be edited to improve the GUI appearance/usability ?

Version that I have installed:

[image]

**Edit (response to Answer)**

The result of the sequence that was provided is the following, which is unusable:

[image]

**Edit 2 in response to Answer**

I had tried that before posting.  That serves no useful purpose.  The result is shown here.

[image: Preference Editor offers no help]

Notable, it had no impact on the Directory Change pop-up either, so there must be some configuration files, for either tkEclipse or TclTk itself which would allow me to change the defaults.  Is there at "tweak" tool, like for GNOME Tweak that would manage the TclTk preferences for various colours?

Answer (score 0):

I can only imagine that this is caused by your desktop environment using some kind of "dark" mode/theme.  Normally, all text in tkeclipse is black.

To check whether the problem is with the underlying Tcl/Tk toolkit, try from a shell:

```
$ wish
% tk_chooseDirectory
```

This should pop up a readable directory chooser, but apparently doesn't in your environment.  I think this is because some "theme" setting of your desktop changes the default colours for Tk applications, leading to non-contrasting fore/background combinations. Changing your desktop theme might help.

What you can try from within tkeclipse itself is to open **Tools/TkECLiPSe Preference Editor** and set a **Default background colour for widgets**.  Something light, e.g. **lightgrey** or **azure** will probably work best.

Comment: Updated original question with output of suggested commands.

Comment: Does the content of    /usr/share/tcltk/tk8.6/ttk/   act as a global override for tcltk, including tkeclipse ?  Or can I tell tkeclipse to use one of the defined themes ?

Comment: @Eric I can't reproduce the effect you are having, and haven't seen it anywhere else. Changing background colour works perfectly for me, it even automatically selects a contrasting text colour, including for the directory chooser.  To further investigate, please contact me via the email given at http://eclipseclp.org/bugs.html